# Duplicate documents if 2 people are travelling UK standard visitor visa?

Tags: uk, paperwork, standard-visitor-visas, premium-services

I'm applying for a UK standard visitor visa along with my wife who is a home maker and financially dependent on me for day to day expenses, should i upload my set of documents in with her application also or just mentioning her passport no in my application and my passport no in her application link our application for eco ? Has anyone had experience with this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I personally haven't had experience with this but as per the UK standard visitor visa documents guide provided on this link :
https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/visitor-visa-guide-to-supporting-documents/guide-to-supporting-documents-visiting-the-uk

`You do not need to provide multiple copies of the same documents if you’re applying as a family or group at the same time.`

but recently one of my acquaintances applied for a standard visitor visa for his parents from India, and just to be on the safe side, he added all the documents of his father's (FD, Assets, Bank Statements) with his mother's application as well. Maybe others with more experience can shed some light on this.

Comment: Thanks theukvisitor, appreciate the help.